# IE 9 Issue : Not getting success response in Ajax call

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, internet-explorer-9

I am facing a problem in IE9 while making an Ajax call to REST API. 
In IE 9, I am not getting success response, while in all other browsers  it works fine, I get  success response in Chrome, FF (Even in IE 10 & 11). 
I get error response in IE 9 as ‘Access Denied’ and in console, it shows HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
Also this ajax call is from http to https.

I tried using jsonp as well, but API doesn't return jsonp response.
Note: This is simple application and no back-end is involved.

Below is my Ajax code.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://myurl to REST API/',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json,
        data: {
            'select': "sum(message_count)",
            'timeRange': timeInterval
        },
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(AppFramework.constants.USER_NAME + ":" + AppFramework.constants.PASSWORD)
        },
        success: function(result) {
            AppFramework.messageCcount = result.environments[0].metrics[0].values[0];
            console.log(AppFramework.messageCcount);
        },
             error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
   }
    });
```

Any help appriciated

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are asking questions about IE9 now but will still provide answer here.

Try setting the cache property to false in your AJAX request. Older versions of IE sometimes tend to cache all AJAX requests and will not allow the browser to use the updated result. You can use one or all of the following to overcome this:

1. Change type from `GET` to `Post`
2. Try cache prevention – Try to append a dynamic string (current Time if possible) at the end of your URL request. This will make all your requests unique & will prevent browser from using the cached response.
3. In your response header, try adding `"Cache-Control","no-cache,no-store"` to explicitly tell the browser to disable caching of this request.
4. Disable cache y simply adding “`cache:false`” in your AJAX call.